# Can I increase performance by using viewcontainer instead of viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

If I use viewcontainers instead of viewcontrollers , will it increase app performance? I'm thinking it's like using fragments in android instead of activity, and that it's better to use viewcontainers in regards to memory.

Comment: Container views on iOS contain... well... view controllers. So you'll have no performance improvement but probably the other way around. Use `UIViewController` alone, they're very efficient.

Comment: Impossible to say, without knowing what your app is going to do. If you want to display an image on a portion of the screen, for example, it will *likely* be much more efficient to simply add an image view to your current view. If you want to display a live-updating chart on a portion of the screen, it may be more efficient to have the logic and drawing code for that chart in a separate view controller, and load/display it in a container view. But there is no simple "one is better than the other" answer.

Comment: Thanks guys , but i have one more question , if there are about 50 ViewControllers,  can there be any problem? i am worry about memory in heap , when we segue to new controller , it will create new controler , so on

Comment: @RashadShirizada - your question is still too broad. You have 50 ViewControllers... are you trying to display them all on one screen? Will all 50 be used every time the app is used? Will a typical user only see 10 of them in a typical session? Are they 50 single-views with one label on each? iOS does a good job of memory management... if you use a NavigationController you could theoretically push 50 VCs and *not* have memory issues... you could use a PageController and a max of 3 VCs would be loaded at any one time. Still no simple answer.